# HTTP request failed error when using @kubernetes/client-node package

Tags: kubernetes

I currently have the following node in typescript/node.js:

```
import * as k8s from '@kubernetes/client-node';
....
const kubeConfig = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kubeConfig.loadFromDefault();
const api = kubeConfig.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);
```

However, the above code produces the following error (I am sure it is the above lines as the output from the lines directly above are present, while if the error occurred from the subsequent lines another error message would've been thrown with the way I set up the code):

```
HttpError: HTTP request failed
    at Request._callback (/usr/tools/node_modules/@kubernetes/client-node/dist/gen/api/coreV1Api.js:4008:36)
    at self.callback (/usr/tools/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Request.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Request.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
```

The version of `@kubernetes/client-node` I am using is `0.18.0` - does anyone know of a possible cause for the above error/a possible fix or even a suggestion for troubleshooting?